# Rails MiniTest 'post' method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, minitest

I'm receiving the following error when I try to run my request specs:

```
POST :: /users/:id/authentications request::successful request#test_0001_Adds an authentication record to a user:
NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007fa607163028>:0x007fa6070012c0>
  test/requests/authentications_test.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

Here's the test itself:

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe "POST :: /users/:id/authentications request" do
  describe "successful request" do
    it "Adds an authentication record to a user" do
      user = create_user

      post user_authentications_path(user)

      response.status.must_equal "200"
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the `minitest_helper.rb` file:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

Dir[Rails.root.join("test/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
end

# database cleaner
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

class MiniTest::Spec
  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

class RequestTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  register_spec_type(/request$/, self)
end
```

Relevant versions of things:
Rails: 3.2.13
minitest-rails: 0.9.2
minitest-rails-capybara: 0.9.0

It really doesn't make sense that I can't call `post`. It looks like every other example out the web can do it just fine.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot going on in your test helper. It seems that you have copied several different approaches to running minitest in your rails tests. I suggest the following:

Remove the following from your test helper:

```
# database cleaner
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

class MiniTest::Spec
  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

class RequestTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  register_spec_type(/request$/, self)
end
```

Add the following to your test helper:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Register "request" tests to be handled by IntegrationTest
  register_spec_type(/Request( ?Test)?\z/i, self)
end
```